# Abuse of "minimal understanding" close reason

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The full reason text is

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"

but the "Questions asking for code" part seems to be gone in many minds.

Let's look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294286/why-am-i-getting-an-undefined-array): User didn't show enough understanding to notice, that if compiler complains about not defined variable, the best solution would be to define it.
But it isn't a question asking for code, so that reason does not apply. Yet it already has a vote with that reason.
As I lately switched from answering question to close votes review, I can see it happens often. Probably because no other close reason fits better.

So:

1. Do you agree that such questions should be closed?
2. What is a proper close reason in this case?
3. How to help close-voters pick a right reason instead of abusing "minimal understanding" one?

Comment: That one could simply be closed as "unclear what you're asking". The only reason it was answered is because the answerer was aware of a previous question and the code it had in it.

Comment: Don't hesitate to type in your own custom close reason.  The willingness to take the time to do so is inversely proportional to the quality of the question.  That's not "abuse".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. The one stated. Minimal understanding of the problem includes not understanding *clear* compiler output.
3. There is no abuse.

Comment: So the "Questions asking for code" reason part should be removed?

Comment: That depends a bit on what you mean by "asking for code" @TadeuszKopec. I'd argue that any debugging question is implicitly asking for it. Even when there is no "please give me some code which...".

Comment: @TadeuszKopec - You can't have failing compilation without code...